# How to save DataGridView multiple rows per record in c# windows form

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

After 24 Hours i have found nothing about this solution.

In Windows Form c# i have created a sales system where i can add multiple items in DataGridView, one item details in only 1 row with Price, Quantity,Discount,Amount.
2nd item details with another item name and all will be same in 2nd row Price,Quantity,Discount,Amount(See the screen shot to know what i am trying to say)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/73fvR.png

So i want to add multiple rows for per customer record in MS SQL Server how can i save?

I can add only first row with all customer details but 2nd and 3rd row how can i also save this? See my code to add rows in database

```
try
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(str);
            con.Open();
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("Sales_Details",con);
                sc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                //sc = new SqlCommand("Insert into Sales_Order(Item_Name,Quantity,Price,Amount,Discount,Total_Amount) Values (@Item_Name,@Quantity,@Price,@Amount,@Discount,@Total_Amount)", con);
                sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item_Name", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Discount",dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
                sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_Amount", dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);

                sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item_Code", textBox6.Text);
                sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOS", S_Date.Text);
                sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customer_Name", S_CustName.Text);
                sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Paid", textBox3.Text);
                sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@R_Balance", textBox4.Text);
                sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tot_Qty", textBox5.Text);

                sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Successfully Saved");
                S_Clear();
            }

            dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

I am saving the row and other details like this

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: As you said, first row is added correctly. On second iteration, does it go to `catch` or simply goes out of the loop? And mention what is `S_Clear()` does. And ensure even on the first iteration, you are not getting `null` for `DataGrid.Rows[].Cells[].Value`.

Comment: Yes first row added correctly it goes to catch and S_Clear() is method for clearing textBoxes.. i want to add all rows in database per customer record?

Comment: Why are you clearing text boxes in for loop? Clear them outside `for`.

Comment: Yes i have done at outside the for loop but nothing happened please any solution to solve this problem